# A very strange and specific pathogen

Tags: biology, diseases

The pathogen is dormant, spread amongst the lymph nodes and other places within an animal commonly found in places of relatively high temperatures, near volcanoes and similar locations. It remains dormant due to the high body temperature of the animal and surrounding environments. When the animal is instantly transferred to a place with much colder temperatures than what it has acclimatised to, it undergoes a 'coldstroke', having seizures and nausea. The pathogen awakens due to the flood of stress hormones and the drop in temperature, killing the creature within 15 seconds. How can it act this fast? Why doesn't it activate if the creature is in a cold place, yet say in boiling water?

Comment: This would be an ectothermic animal like an axolotl, I take it.   Endothermic animals like wombats do not experience big swings in body temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enzymes and activation**

Bacteria, viruses and cells work with enzymes. These help with getting things into and out of the 'organisms', among many other things they do. These enzymes can be used to identify the organisms as foreign organisms or your own. The pathogen could mimic those enzymes, or hide inside some cells in the lymph nodes. This can be in the lymph nodes themselves, or possibly B, T or white blood cells, which comprise immune system.

There are pathogens that only activate under certain circumstances, as it increases their chance of survival. When going to colder climates, hormones could activate that signal the pathogen. Alternatively enzymes get more active at certain temperatures, which can be at a lower temperature for the pathogen. Possibly when it activates, it'll stop mimicking or simply take over the infected cells. When this happens, it'll attack something vital. If it's spread throughout the lymph nodes and the blood, it can simply deconstruct red blood cells on a massive scale throughout the body for it's own purposes. This will deprive the body of oxygen, among other valuable nutrients. The creature would quickly lose consciousness, dying shortly after.

Alternatives that they hide in the blood cells or can filter through the blood brain barrier and spread, laying dormant until a trigger causes them to kiss their host cells and spread out en masse can also happen.

The difficulty about these is the immune system. That is why I suggest it takes this system over and make it work for itself at the right time. Much like aids, it'll be nearly impossible to stop. If it can filter through the blood brain barrier (through enzymes or the olfactory bulb, which is often less shielded), it'll be relatively safe, but some immune systems might still attack it. Mimicking isn't as safe as hiding in cells, especially immune cells.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, however it doesn't answer the last bit of my question, namely: Why doesn't it activate if the creature is in a cold place, yet say in boiling water?

Got any solutions?

Comment: @JeffereyDawson but before that you talk about it the other way around? I thought you just mixed up the last sentence.

Comment: sorry, in hindsight it is confusing. If the creature was in a cold place yet in a hot liquid like boiling water, the virus still activates. why is that?

Comment: If the create is in boiling water, the creature is not in a cold place...

Comment: @JeffereyDawson because the visual stimuli create different RNA that the virus pick up on? Or a smell? Or picks up an altitude difference? Honestly it gets pretty unbelievable (though plausible in a far away sense), but maybe someone has a better option.